# Regex pattern for Driving Licence validation

Tags: regex, salesforce

I am trying to write a regex pattern which should allow Ontario driving licences in the below formats

Requirement: Regex should be any letter followed by 14 digits and there could be 
1 or more special char between the letter and digit or between those 14 digits

- D6101-40706-60905
- D6101 40706 60905
- D61014070660905
- A1234 - 12345 - 12345

  Not to allow following pattern: That is more 14 numeric digits with or without non space characters.
- D6101 40706 609053
- D6101070660905313

**Regex:^[A-Za-z][0-9/\W/]{2,20}$**

Comment: You can try `'^[A-Za-z](?=(\W*?\d\W*?){14}$)'` if you are just looking for a match condition. If it is a regex selection, you can do `'^[A-Za-z](?=(\W*?\d\W*?){14}$)[\W\d]+'`

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I just noticed your comment, which pre-dated my (similar) answer. If you'd like to offer an answer I will delete mine. Note, incidentally, the OP used the word "validation" in the title, so I don't think your #2 is relevant. Also, though a detail, it would seem that characters after the first must be digits or "special characters", which the examples suggest are spaces and hyphens.

Comment: Gomathi, many questions refer to "special characters", without defining what they are. Rather than using that term I suggest you provide a list of the characters that are permitted. If you forget a few (not here, I expect), that's harmless, as they can simply be added later. If you wish to reject, for example, `A1234 -- -- - 12345 - 12345`, you need to be more specific of how the hyphens and spaces can be arranged. For example, you could say that between each string of digits there could be no space, one space, one hyphen or a hyphen preceded and followed by one space. Be precise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regular expression

```
^[A-Z](?:\d[- ]*){14}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iW31BV/2/)

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^        # match beginning of line
[A-Z]    # match a capital letter
(?:      # begin a non-cap grp
  \d     # match a digit
  [- ]*  # match a hypthen or space 0+ times
)        # end non-cap grp
{14}     # execute non-cap grp 14 times
$        # match end of line
```

Comment: Cary - Thanks a lot for your reply. It works. However, am facing another issue where the masking works without any additional text. For example, D61014070660905 works fine. However when the pattern is mentioned with any other text in the form a sentence it's not working. The following test data fails -"This is my driving licence D61014070660905" where masking does not work for the licence number in the sentence.

Comment: Simply change the anchors `^` and `$` to `\b`, the later being a *word break*.

Comment: I just removed ^ & $. It worked with sentence as well. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

`/d`
// this represents ANY one digit[0-9]
`/w`
// represents ANY one word

`//if you wanted to repeat this 14 times you could add curly braces and the number inside`

`/^(\d{14})$/`

Answer (score 0):

```
"^(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2})( )|([A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}))((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{7}" +
                            "|([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[\\/][a-zA-Z]{3}[\\/][0-9]{2}[\\/][0-9]{5})" +
                            "|([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}(N)[\\-]{1}((19|20)[0-9][0-9])[\\-][0-9]{7})" +
                            "|([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{14})" +
                            "|([a-zA-Z]{2}[\\-][0-9]{13})$"
```

This will validate almost all Indian States Driving licenses with the latest numbering patterns.